# Problem with Mahjongg in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gnome

Ok I have a problem with the game Mahjongg. It's the GNOME version of the game that comes by default in Ubuntu and other distros, but when I used the ricotz testing ppa aka the "GNOME Shell" ppa and updated my system Mahjongg would no longer launch. I tried uninstalling and installing the package from Synaptic, but I think I have to purge it and then install it.

So it boils down to; How do I purge and reinstall Mahjongg from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the solution is to purge and reinstall as you suggest:

Generally, the command to purge a program `foo` is `sudo apt-get purge foo`, or `sudo apt-get remove --purge foo`. So for this case (the package in question is `gnome-mahjongg`) you need `sudo apt-get purge gnome-mahjongg`, which will also uninstall the `mahjongg` package (these are two separate packages, but `mahjongg` depends on `gnome-mahjongg`.

Alternatively, in Synaptic, you can choose the option "Mark for complete removal", this is synonymous with `purge`.

Then, you can just reinstall as usual (i.e. `sudo apt-get install mahjongg` or simply install via Synaptic)

If this still doesn't work, an alternative would be the KDE Mahjongg game, `kmahjongg`, which can be installed simply by typing `sudo apt-get install kmahjongg`.

Comment: So the GNOME Game called `Mahjong` is called `foo` in code? Just like Files is called Nautilus in code (Yes I know that Files used to be Nautilus as I first tried Linux back in 2010 with Ubuntu 10.04). The name `foo` doesn't seem right

Comment: @davidbuddy9 No, sorry for the confusion. `foo` is just meant as a general placeholder name ("Insert package here", if you will). I'll edit the answer a bit.